# Excel: Using the return value of logical test as return value of IF function

Tags: excel, if-statement, return-value

this is taken from an excel worksheet with no VBA involved. Is there any way to reconstruct

```
=IF(ISERROR(function_return),something_else,function_return)
```

such that the term `function_return` will only be stated once explicitly. Because `function_return` could have a lot of parameters that I want to adjust at one place only, instead of at both instances.
In other languages I would try to use

```
var foo = function_return(many_many_arguments)
=IF(ISERROR(foo),something_else,foo)
```

Can something like this be realized inside of **one cell**?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I'm interpreting correctly (disregard if so :) ), but it sounds like you could simulate this with a named range. For example, if I have the function `=SUM(A1:A5)`, I could create a named range `Foo` that was equal to `=SUM(A1:A5)`. Then, I could write a formula like:

```
=IF(ISERROR(Foo),"Something else",Foo)
```

If `Foo` calculated properly, it would return the value; otherwise, it would return "Something else". You could expand `Foo` to cover whatever formula you are trying to calculate. You could then use `Foo` in any formula without having to retype the range.

[image]

Comment: Great, that sounds promising! I guess it does the job.

Comment: @dieterw Awesome, hope it helps! Happy to troubleshoot if anything comes up.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Excel 2007 onwards, there's a function EXACTLY to do this - Look at `iferror()`